# App not shown in 2.1 Market

Tags: android, google-play

I published several free and paid app in the Market. I recently get
several complains from customers about not finding my app in the 2.1
Market. Even if they have bought them before, they can't find it in
the market or their download list after updating to 2.1.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is? My apps only require minimal SDK 3..

Thanks a lot!!

**Update:**
It looks like that they are not shown because they have copy protection enabled. Is this a bug in the Market?

Comment: How are we supposed to know, when you don't tell us anything about the apps...like, say, their names?

Comment: How are these people updating to 2.1?  By installing some custom ROM on their rooted phones?  Do you have the copyright protection enabled on your apps?

Comment: @CommonsWare, here is some names: App Protector Lite, SMS Cleaner Pro, Call Log Cleaner Pro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having this difficulty also using my ROM OpenEclair **(www.openeclair.org**)
This only occurs on 2.1, but if it is a custom ROM - they may run into the trouble that the dev is using a Market from 1.6 instead of 2.1
Another possibility is using a 2.1 Market from a diff phone (such as the Droid Eris's Market on a Dream/Magic)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer and it has to do with recent changes in Google market filters on Jun 1st, 2010. Take a look at the following link:
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html

I found in my case that the app was hidden in some phones since I had included the following entry in my manifest:

Answer (score 0):

It is because copy-protection is depreciated. Every build or release needs to be whitelisted by google as secure enough to have copy-protected apps. That way they can "ensure" it wont be copied.

From:
http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html

"Replacement for copy protection

Android Market Licensing is a flexible, secure mechanism for controlling access to your applications. It effectively replaces the copy-protection mechanism offered on Android Market and gives you wider distribution potential for your applications."

Use the licensing instead in order to hit a larger audience or customer base.